# Erro de certificado

Tags: http

Estou tentando acessar o site e enviar documentos e está dando problema de HTTP, apareceu a seguinte mensagem.
Ocorreu um erro ao fazer a solicitação HTTP para *https://mni1g....br/intercomunicacao.* Isso pode ser devido ao fato de que o certificado do servidor não está configurado corretamente com HTTP.SYS no caso HTTPS. Isso também pode ser causado por uma incompatibilidade da ligação de segurança entre o cliente e o servidor.

Como eu devo por ?

Answer (score -4):

Isso acontece pq vc esta tentando fazer uma requisição sem certificado SSL, usando o http ao inves do https, para corrigir, antes de cada solicitação sem SSL coloque:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```